# HTCaccess rediect repeating the subfolder

Tags: html

I am trying to redirect the main page to a blog.  I am using the htcaccess code like this

```
Redirect / http://coolefitness.com/blog
```

The result is  http://coolefitness.com/blogblogbloglblogblog

no idea why it is repeating the blog.  I haven't told it to do that.  I don't even know how I would make that loop happen.

Here is my full htcaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Redirect /index.html http://coolefitness.com/index.php
Redirect /members.html http://coolefitness.com/members.php
Redirect /what-is-coolefitness.html http://coolefitness.com/what-is-coolefitness.php
Redirect /instructors.html http://coolefitness.com/instructors.php



RewriteEngine On

#Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http:/coolefitness.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]

Redirect / http://coolefitness.com/blog

ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /404.php

FallbackResource payment/app.php



# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

I have tried doing a rewrite, but that isn't working.  I have removed it and the issue still happens.

Comment: Is your file named correctly? It should be `htaccess` and not `htcaccess`...

Comment: You're also missing another `/` after `http:/` on line 14.